# Java native big jshortarray with more than int elements

Tags: java, java-native-interface

How can I create a jshortarray with 545460846912 elements

```
 retval = env->NewShortArray((long) 545460846912);  // allocate
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
..test.cpp:296:42: warning: implicit conversion from 'long' to 'jsize' (aka 'int') changes value from 545460846912 to 320 [-Wconstant-conversion]
    env->SetShortArrayRegion(retval, 0 , (long) 545460846912, (short const *)b); 
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~             ^~
```

Try to mimic this code

```
int nGetEncoderFrameSize = (int) LibSpeex.nGetEncoderFrameSize(nInitSpxEncoder);
```

and it returns 545460846912 for my file

I need to make an short array with that size

```
 short[] sArr = new short[nGetEncoderFrameSize];
```

and then call it:

```
long nEncodeBuffer = LibSpeex.nEncodeBuffer(nInitSpxEncoder, sArr, bArr, 65536);
```

Is it possible to create that big jshortArray?

How can I solve it?

Comment: 545460846912 is 0x7f00000140, which looks like a stack and/or kernel  address. I think you're chasing a red herring. The JNI defines the size parameter of `New<Primitive>Array` as a `jsize` anyway, so you cannot create arrays with more than 2**32 items.

Comment: @Botje Nevermind that 545460846912 won't fit into `int nGetEncoderFrameSize` anyway...

Comment: Actually debugged it. It seg faults on null ptr deref in the lib. Tried passing it WAV, and PCM as short array input and expected output to by in byte array. So I guess I miss some info. Close it on my end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I create a jshortarray with 545460846912 elements

You **can't**.

Per the [Java 9 Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.4) (bolding mine):

> **Arrays must be indexed by `int` values**; `short`, `byte`, or `char` values may also be used as index values because they are subjected to unary numeric promotion (§5.6.1) and become `int` values.
>
> An attempt to access an array component with a `long` index value results in a compile-time error.
>
> All array accesses are checked at run time; an attempt to use an index that is less than zero or greater than or equal to the length of the array causes an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException to be thrown.

The wording for [Java 17 is identical](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.4).

[Java `int` values are limited in range to](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1)  (again, bolding mine):

> **4.2.1. Integral Types and Values**
>
> The values of the integral types are integers in the following ranges:
>
> - For `byte`, from -128 to 127, inclusive
> - For `short`, from -32768 to 32767, inclusive
> - **For `int`, from -2147483648 to 2147483647, inclusive**
> - For `long`, from -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807, inclusive
> - For `char`, from '\u0000' to '\uffff' inclusive, that is, from 0 to 65535

2147483647 is smaller than 545460846912.